# Oracle NUMBER value getting converted when querying in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

When doing a direct query from toad I get a value of `.00089`. However when I query the value using an OracleConnection object the number gets converted to `.0019`.

I assumed that it was getting converted when I assigned it to a value, however, i am becoming more and more confident that it is getting converted in the actual query NOT in the conversion from the query results to the variable on the C# side.

I have tried

```
reader.getDecimal(1) 
Convert.toDouble(reader[1].ToString)
```

Regardless of how I do the reader assign to variable I always get `.0019`.

Any help here is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Post your schema and queries.

Comment: Try fetching the value as a character string, e.g. `SELECT TO_CHAR(your_value) FROM whereever` to see what's really there. That being said, I would tend to trust Toad. YMMV.